# What happens to PostgresSQL config values if the settings are commented out in postgresql.conf?

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know what is the behavior of Postgres config setting values if the settings are commented out in postgresql.conf?

For example, what would be the behavior of these settings: 'client_min_messages', 'log_min_messages', 'log_min_error_statement'. Would they still default to their defaults mentioned in the Postgres docs?

```
# - When to Log -

#client_min_messages = notice       # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error

#log_min_messages = warning     # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_min_error_statement = error    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)
# Log all statements taking longer than 1 second.  Useful for pgBadger analysis.
# Could be increased to 30 seconds in Beta to reduce log size.
log_min_duration_statement = 1000   # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds
```

Thanks
lmk

Comment: Yes. In the absence of a configured value, the default value is used.

Comment: Thanks @jmelesky i am just wanting to understand the expected behavior as i could not find that clarified in the docs explicitly. In other words, can we say that only for the settings we want do we need to add an entry in the file & if there is a case where we don't need ANY non-defaults we can keep the file empty?

Comment: I genuinely don't know how postgres would react to a *completely* empty conf file, but, yes, in general, you could use it to only store the delta between default and intended config.

Comment: Thanks @jmelesky. It would be nice to have this behavior documented in the docs so we can count on it to be true always. For example, the docs say that one can pass settings as command file flags & they override the conf file setting. Btw, i can see that i can do a "SHOW ALL" & see all the settings.